# What is the Largest file size we can put in application files directory in android?

Tags: android, file

Dynamically i  am putting the  files in application files directory .if i put lengthy file  then it is crashing.What is the Largest file  size we can put in application files directory in android?

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash. The largest possible file size is however much free space exists.

Comment: It's a linux file system, probably what's actually crashing it is that you're dealing with a large chunk of data in the heap, not the filesystem itself.  (E.g., if you're storing a huge bitmap, it's probably the bitmap --- not the file)